# Storing the values of two array lists on a dynamic 3 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I have the following data which shows the exact time and date when someone turns on and off their light in their room stored into 2 array lists:

1. 2015-11-09T10:04:22  1
2. 2015-11-09T11:45:14  0
3. 2015-11-09T11:45:32  1
4. 2015-11-09T15:13:56  0
5. 2015-11-10T10:17:17  1
6. 2015-11-10T11:20:04  0
7. 2015-11-10T12:28:41  1
8. 2015-11-10T13:04:46  0
9. 2015-11-10T13:05:48  1
10. 2015-11-10T13:35:15 0
11. 2015-11-11T13:10:04 1
12. 2015-11-11T15:46:18 0

First array list contains the datetime and second array list contains the value that shows if someone turned on/off the light.

I want to sort the data into a dynamic three dimensional array where the date (without the time) will be the key and for each date I can store the time I observed a change and what kind of change it was (0 or 1 in this case).

What type of data structure should I use? I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: So, your question is "what data structure to use?"

Comment: Yeah do u have any ideas?

Comment: @A 3D array is a data structure you can use, if this is a requirement "I want to sort the data into a dynamic three dimensional array".

Comment: Yeah but I want it to be dynamic as I don't know how many changes I will have for each date. In essence I am looking for something like a 3 dimensional array list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider a Map as a good container for your use case.  The map allows the date to be the key, and creating a SwitchEvent class (holds the time and switch state on/off) allows a List to be used to store the events for each day.

```
Map<LocalDate, List<SwitchEvent>> eventContainer
```

Example usage follows:

```
public class LightSwitchMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<LocalDate, List<SwitchEvent>> eventContainer = new HashMap<>();

    // Example of a light switch OFF on Jan 1, 2016 at 9:45)
    LocalDate eventDate1 = LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 1);
    SwitchEvent event1 = new SwitchEvent(LocalTime.of(9, 45), 0);

    addSwitchEvent(eventContainer, eventDate1, event1);

    // Light goes on
    SwitchEvent event2 = new SwitchEvent(LocalTime.of(9, 55), 1);
    addSwitchEvent(eventContainer, eventDate1, event2);

}

static void addSwitchEvent(Map<LocalDate, List<SwitchEvent>> eventContainer, LocalDate eventDate, SwitchEvent event) {
    List<SwitchEvent> dayEvents = eventContainer.get(eventDate);
    if (dayEvents == null) {
        dayEvents = new ArrayList<SwitchEvent>();
        eventContainer.put(eventDate, dayEvents);
    }
    dayEvents.add(event);
}

static class SwitchEvent {
    final LocalTime eventTime;  // Time of the light switch
    final int switchState;      // 0=off, 1=on
    public SwitchEvent(LocalTime eventTime, int switchState) {
        this.eventTime = eventTime;
        this.switchState = switchState;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really helpful!

Comment: Please for my understanding, can you explain why you chose the other answer?

Comment: Oh I am sorry I thought I could pick more than one answers. I chose yours now :)

Comment: Thank you. You can always _upvote_ any or all answer if you feel they are useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

An SQL table could also be your option.

Your requirement for filtering on dates, sorting on times and detecting on/off gets satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The data structures that comes into mind are `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`. Here you have two options.

1. If you know the number of dates you'll be sorting then an `array` of `LinkedList` would suffice.
2. If you don't know the number of dates you'll be sorting then a use an `ArrayList` of `LinkedList`